# Laravel 5.2 Testing : Test is not running

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, testing, laravel-5

I have create a test via terminal with command :

`php artisan make:test UserTest`

Now i want to run the test with the following command :

`vendor/bin/UserTest`

But it returns

`bash: vendor/bin/UserTest: No such file or directory`

PHPunit is Installed. I have checked.

Am i missing something ?

Comment: You should just be able to do `phpunit` in your root Laravel directory. You don't bash PHP files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run tests with this command from Laravel root project directory:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

If you want to run custom package tests, use:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit packages/name/package/
```